# error with using excel parser code

Tags: c++, objective-c, excel, xml-parsing

I was trying to make a project that can parse excel file (.xls) and i found an open source library "libxls" on [libxls.sourceforge.net](http://libxls.sourceforge.net)  (libxls-0.2.0-i386-apple.tar.gz) which seems to be very handy. According to description on that website i simply need to:

1. `#include <libxls/xls.h>`
2. add `libxlsreader.a` file into my project
3. declare a pointer: `xlsWorkBook* pWB;`
4. call the function: `pWB=xls_open("file.xls", "UTF-8");`

then the pWB should be pointing to my xls file containing each worksheet and all the cells.

However, when i followed this instruction. i got below error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>    "_xls_open", referenced from:
>       _"my function name that calls xls_open" in "the .o file containing my calling function"
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

However, the `xlsWorkBook* pWB` has no problem.

I tried to call the `xls_open`function from both .mm and .cpp file and none of them worked.

I wanted to ask this question on their website but the discussion there is very old. So has anyone happened to try this excel parser library as well? can anyone help me why i can not use the `xls_open` function? Any help is appreciated! thank you!

Comment: This is not the place to get technical support on some code you downloaded from the Internet. Ask your question on the site that hosts the code.

Comment: You might want to try building the library instead of using the .a file.